# When I migrate I get this error django.db.utils.DataError: value too long for type character varying(10)

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-migrations, migrate

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bsL3w.png)

Encountering "The specified object could not be found" error during Django migrations. Tried various solutions, including rolling back migrations, resetting the database, and checking foreign keys. Still seeking a resolution.

Comment: Please send the migration that is failing and check as this means you are adding more string than allowed by the field.

Comment: Do you have a CharField with max_length=10? try to change it to more than 10..

Comment: Please read [Why should I not upload images of code/data/errors?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551/354577). Instead, format code as a [code block]. The easiest way to do this is to paste the code as text directly into your question, then select it and click the code block button.